# Computing the Laurent series for $1/z^2$ about $z_0=1$

Tags: laurent-series

I'm trying to compute the Laurent series of $f(z) = 1/z^2$ about the point $z_0=1$. Looking at my notes, it appears that I need to compute a series for $|z-1| < 1$ and one for $|z-1|>1$, due to the singularity at the point $1$.

Could someone show me how to compute each of these series? I'm a bit confused on where to begin.

EDIT: The problem says to "Write all Laurent series of the following functions on annuli centered at $z_0$," so I feel like there should be two series: one valid for $|z-1|<1$ and another valid for $|z-1|>1$.

Comment: Note $f$ is analytic at $z_0=1$, so you just need to compute the taylor series; which will only converge in radius 1.

Comment: I understand that's what I need to do for the series valid for $|z-1|<1$, but what about the other series, namely $|z-1|>1$?

Comment: Of the following function*S*, so I believe that your exercise was asking you to find the Laurent series of many functions, with respect to the point $x_0=1$.

Comment: This is one part of a multipart question...

Comment: I think you are a bit confused about *the definition* of a Laurent series.

Comment: Here's my confusion...I've seen several examples where multiple Laurent series are computed for a function, based on the location of the singularities. Since $z=0$ is a singularity here, shouldn't we also compute a Laurent series on the annulus $|z-1|>1$ that vanishes at infinity?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What I think OP means is that (for example) if $f(z)= 1/(z-1)$ at $z_0 = 0$ we have $\frac{1}{z-1} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ for $|z|<1$ and $\frac{1}{z-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}$ for $|z|>1$, i.e. two series defined in two different annuli.

Answer (score 1):

$z_0=1$ is not a singularity for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$, hence the Laurent series is just a Taylor series, and since:
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = 1+2z+3z^2+\ldots = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}(j+1)z^j$$
around the origin, you have:
$$\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^j(j+1)(z-1)^j$$
around one. You can check that the radius of convergence, one, is exactly the distance from the closest singularity, the origin.

Comment: But shouldn't there be a second Laurent series, valid for $|z-1|>1$? The problem statement says to compute ALL of the Laurent series.

Comment: There is just ONE series, and it is a Taylor series, since the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z=1$.

Comment: Why isn't there a series for values beyond the singularity at $0$?

Comment: ...because the problem statement says "on all annuli centered at $z_0$"

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: If you take a Taylor series centered in $x_0$, you cannot demand that the radius of convergence of such a series goes over the distance from the closest singularity. The Laurent series is a series defined in a point.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are after can be found using the same method as in the answer above.

For $|z| > 1$ we have

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{(1-1/z)^2} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{j+2}$$

so

$$\frac{1}{z^2} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j(j+1)\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^{j+2}$$

for $|z-1| > 1$